# Creating data model to accept all JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

So I'm creating an endpoint using a data model called Chat that will accept data in this JSON form and store it in the database.

```
[{
    "ID": "123456",
    "Chat": [{
            "ID": "1",
            "Message": "User: that's a nice car Dylan: thanks",
            "PostedBy": "Dylan",
            "PostedOn": "2018-01-23T18:25:43.511Z"
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "Message": "User: that's a really nice car Terry: thanks ",
            "PostedBy": "Terry",
            "PostedOn": "2018-02-23T18:25:43.511Z"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "Message": "User: that's the best car Roger: thanks",
            "PostedBy": "Roger",
            "PostedOn": "2018-03-23T18:25:43.511Z"
        }
    ]
}]
```

This is what I have currently and when I send data to the endpoint it only stores the ID, and nothing else in the database. Any thoughts/guidance is appreciated on how I could alter my model to accept the entirety of the data that is being sent.

```
public class Chat
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string message { get; set; }

    public string postedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? postedOn { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You could start by using json2csharp.com

Comment: You didnt show how you get from point A to point B, but "message" != "Message".  Notice how the casing matches for the property that works?  VS will build the class for you if you let it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Try matching the case of the properties... i.e. `Message`, `PostedBy` and `PostedOn`

Comment: 1) Please specify the framework and/or serializer you are using.  Is it [tag:wcf]?  [tag:asp.net-web-api2]?  [tag:asp.net-core]?  Different frameworks use different serializers, and some are case-sensitive (`DataContractJsonSerializer`) while some are not (Json.NET).  2) Please share the actual signature of the endpoint method so we can see how it uses your current data model.  A [mcve] would be ideal; without it we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but it seems to me like you're using a class that represents a single message-instance (the class `Chat`) to attempt to store a whole list of Chat-data.

If I'm right, the only reason it actually stores `ID` is that it by chance happens to have the same name for two different levels in your data; one for the outer list (the whole set - and this is what is stored), and one for each of the inner chat-items.

Try to add this class, and use that instead (or rather in addition, since it actually *contains* a list of instances of your already existing class `Chat`):

```
public class ChatThread
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Chat> Chat { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ID` which is being stored on your object is not the `ID` from the `Chat` object, but rather the higher `ID` definition which is common to your Chat objects.

You're were really close, if we discount the fact that you have not taken into consideration that C# is a case-sensitive language. 
The "higher" layer is composed of a String `ID`, but also of an array of `Chat` objects, so you should create a `Class` that holds the definition of these two properties.

```
public class JsonClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public Chat[] Chat { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Since there exist multiple `Chat` objects for the `JsonClass` ID property, you have to make it into a collection of some sort. I chose an array, but you can use other `Collection` objects, such as a `List`.